# Searching for text (Ctrl+F) across hidden spans

Tags: html, css, firefox

Is it possible to search for text using your browser's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> function across three `span` tags if the middle tag is set to hidden? For example:

```
<span class="visibleText">Trying</span>
<span class="hiddenText">to search</span>
<span class="visibleText">text.</span>
```

If `.hiddenText` is set to `display:none`, the web browser will show "Trying text." If you search using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in a web browser, however, you will stop matching the string after "Trying ". You can highlight the whole phrase "Trying text" and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, which will pop the phrase into your search box, but clicking the find-next-match button will yield no results.

Is there any way of making that whole phrase searchable? For an example, check out: http://jsfiddle.net/surrealmind/qo2ens33/.

Comment: With "whole phrase", do you mean "Trying text." or "Trying to search text."?

Comment: "Trying text." Sorry, and good point: I should have been more specific.

Comment: --And thanks to ctwheels for a (since deleted) way of getting "Trying to search text" when the middle tag is hidden; I didn't know this was possible, either.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted it, added it back with edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

http://jsfiddle.net/qo2ens33/2/

**HTML**

```
<span class="visibleText">Trying</span>
<div class="hiddenText"><span>to search</span></div>
<span class="visibleText">text</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.hiddenText{
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

---

This works too

http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/qo2ens33/5/

**HTML**

```
<span class="visibleText">Trying</span>
<span class="hiddenText">to search</span>
<span class="visibleText">text</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.hiddenText {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    width:0px;
}
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for

---

Ok, I think this is what you're looking for... You can't (as far as I know) search for two separate spans together, so what I've done is I've added the visible spans together

http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/qo2ens33/6/

Using this code:

**JS**

```
var numberOfElements = $(".visibleText").length;
for (var i = 1; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
    $(".visibleText:eq(0)").append(" " + $(".visibleText:eq(1)").text());
    $(".visibleText:eq(1)").remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, these are good methods for finding "Trying to search text". Is there any good way of finding just "Trying text" with "to search" removed?

Comment: I've added another answer to my answers, like the last one?

Comment: Very nice, we are getting somewhere. Ideally, we would not need to use JQuery, but it looks like it might not be possible with just css and html alone, eh? And what about one last wrinkle? What if we wanted to put the .hiddenText back in place? If I set the JQuery to display the .hiddenText after your rearrangement, the formerly hidden text now (obviously) appears at the end of the line instead of in its original position: http://jsfiddle.net/surrealmind/qo2ens33/7/

Comment: By this, do you mean back into the sentence as it was before (and seen)? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Yes, to reconstruct the sentence as if nothing were hidden in the first place: "Trying to search text"

Comment: By george, that does it--thanks! It seems like this should be solvable with simple CSS and html, but I'll gladly accept the Javascript solution.

Comment: If you want an HTML solution, the closest I think you can get is by using the <details> tag. If you're looking for a CSS solution, the closest you can come is using the hover event to show/hide elements. The reason I went with js for the answer, however, was because you specified that you wanted the entire sentence to be "searchable" using Ctrl + F

Answer (score 0):

With this you can find "Trying to search text." but not "Trying text.":

```
.hiddenText{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10000cm;
    left: -10000cm;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qo2ens33/2/)

Comment: Thank you, Oriol; now if we could only find a way to "Trying text."

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you want but it does accomplish "hidden text".  I think the positioning could be tweaked to fit your purpose.

```
.parent {
  height: 2em;
  width: 400px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.hiddenText {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  color: transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
.hiddenText::selection {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nbzv9thL/