# Ctrl+F in hidden text: reveal the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have containers with multiple lines but only the first one visible (`overflow:hidden`). The container is expandable upon a click. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972830 and the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JUtcX/2/)

If someone performs a Ctrl+F with text from the non-visible lines, the browser reports a match but cannot show it (because it's hidden).

**How can I react to Ctrl+F and open the container whether a non-visible text in it was searched for?**

[Update]
Approaches that do not meet all requirements:

1. Listening for Ctrl+F.

   - I have multiple containers and only want to expand those containing the search phrase. Upon listening for Ctrl+F I could only open all containers at once.
   - Does not work on all systems. This is a negligible defect only, though.
2. Chrome-specific workaround ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21093148/1531708))

   - At least also Firefox should be supported

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome search feature (ctrl+f) finds hidden text ( but it's invisible! )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093148/chrome-search-feature-ctrlf-finds-hidden-text-but-its-invisible)

Comment: No duplicate, since the above is Chrome-unique (tested as not working with Firefox 40.0.2) and it would not be able to expand the div - it's merely a hack (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: if the user presses next the content will automatically scroll to the next instance of the word

Comment: @RachelGallen Not in all browsers.

Comment: @PhilLab I tried experimenting with the `onselect` event , but apparently it is not fired on a search result.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937388/listening-to-browser-ctrlf-find-layout-modifications
and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793864/listen-for-events-from-browser-find-window-in-javascript You are able to listen to the keyevents of ctrl + f and react to it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
function find(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 70) {
        document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "block";
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keyup', find, false);
```

```css
#hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  ASDF:
  <div id="hide">
    Hidden
  </div>
</div>
```

- [Listening to browser Ctrl+F/find layout modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937388/listening-to-browser-ctrlf-find-layout-modifications)

> I don't think it is possible to listen to those layout modifications.
>
> When the browser find an element, it is equivalent to call
>   scrollIntoView for the matched element. Thus a scroll event will be
>   fired only if the container div is scrollable.
>
> In the example, the parent style is overflow: hidden;. Thus it does
>   not trigger any scroll event.
>
> It becomes then impossible to listen to these layout change, because
>   the only workaround that exist to listen to scroll event on
>   overflow:hiden element, is to listen to mouse wheel event ...
>
> The bad story is that it is then impossible to prevent user from
>   modifying layout through the browser find, because even if one can
>   prevent Ctrl+F or F3, we can't prevent user from using the Edit-> Find
>   menu in Firefox or IE

JBE

- [Listen for Events from Browser "Find" Window in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793864/listen-for-events-from-browser-find-window-in-javascript)

> I don't know of any way you can listen for a find-like event and if
>   that's supported in any browser it sure isn't a portable solution.
>
> I also don't know what you're trying to achieve but I think that your
>   best option is to listen for the keyboard events that trigger the find
>   window and attempt to cancel them while attempting to emulate the
>   find-toolbar/window with JavaScript of your own. This is however a
>   herculean (and nearly impossible) task due to some browsers
>   customization of keyboard shortcuts depending on the localization (for
>   instance, in IE, en-US uses Ctrl+F (for Find) while pt-PT uses Ctrl+L
>   (for Localizar, meaning find)).
>
> Conclusion: I think you're out of luck there...

Miguel Ventura

- [Searching for text (Ctrl+F) across hidden spans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512436/searching-for-text-ctrlf-across-hidden-spans?rq=1)
- [Chrome search feature (ctrl+f) finds hidden text ( but it's invisible! )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093148/chrome-search-feature-ctrlf-finds-hidden-text-but-its-invisible)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! Unfortunately, this does not work smoothly with multiple expandable containers - either none or all of them have to be opened. The literature that you provided is also interesting, especially the problem with the shortcut localization :-(

Comment: Please note that it wouldn't work for Mac. (Actually, `find()` may be fired using `ctrl` key, but OSX uses `cmd` key instead of `ctrl` key)