# Browser text "Find"(ctrl+f) doesn't search across inline-block span elements (Chrome/Edge issue - Firefox okay)

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <head><style>
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
  </style></head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span>
        Find<span>ing</span>
        Finding
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Both Chrome and MS Edge **don't** show two hits when ctrl+f searching for the term `Finding`. However, Firefox does work and shows both.

That HTML block above is a simplification of content being served by an external service and I'm just curious to find out from those in the know what the expected behaviour of `display: inline-block` is meant to be and which of the browsers is doing the correct thing?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25512592/12419917 suggests something about searching across spans might not work (but in the context of a hidden span between them), so I'm not sure if that's relevant. It certainly seems appropriate to ask again just because there is a definite browser difference in handling this case.